# Keeping space after top gets fixed

Tags: html, css

I have created a function where menu gets fixed when I scroll down.

When that happens, it takes a lot of space with it, as you can [see in my demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h65x3hyb/) all the text goes behind the fixed bar instead.

Is there a way to keep a little bit more space between `.top` which gets fixed and `.content`?

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers. I choose Marcos' one because he was first, but I know the other ones work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to play with the `padding-top` of the content when the `top` is fixed. So the whole solution is:

```
.top.fixed + .content {
    padding-top: 155px;
}
```

Your edited fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h65x3hyb/2/

Comment: Thanks, may I ask how you got padding-top: 155px;?

Comment: 155px is the minimum amount of pixels that it needs to show. The normal thing is equal than the height of the header (in this case 180px) but with 155px is enough to show the text. However you can play with that value to achieve exactly what you want. Good luck :)

Comment: Could also change `top` value of the header (to `-105` in this case) instead of reducing `height`, as the latter may hide the wanted part

Comment: Nice, cleanest solution

Comment: Yeah, it's valid too if there isn't content inside header

Answer (score 1):

please apply the scripts into it.

```
$(function()
{
    $top = $('.top');

  $(window).on('scroll', function()
  {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75)
    {
        $top.addClass('fixed');
      $('.content').css('padding-top:','196px');
    }
    else
    {
        $top.removeClass('fixed');
      $('.content').css('padding-top:','0');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a class to `.content` as well:

```js
$(function() {
  var $top = $('.top'),
    $content = $('.content');

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
      $top.addClass('fixed');
      $content.addClass('margin');
    } else {
      $top.removeClass('fixed');
      $content.removeClass('margin');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  top: 0;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top.fixed {
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.content {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content.margin {
  margin-top: 180px;
  /*height of top*/
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">

</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add padding to your `p` tag and `margin` to content using `jquery`.

```
$(function()
{
    $top = $('.top');

  $(window).on('scroll', function()
  {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75)
    {
        $top.addClass('fixed');
      $(".content").css("marginTop","152px");
    }
    else
    {
        $top.removeClass('fixed');
      $(".content").css("marginTop","0px");
    }
  });
});

p
{
  margin: 0;
  padding-top:20px;
}
```